# Where to create a subversion repository on a server?

Tags: linux, filesystems, best-practices

When managing my own servers, I normally keep data such as svn repositories in `/srv/svnrepo`.

In the organization I currently a part of the SAs have been using `/home/svnrepo`.

My decision to standardize to `/srv/svnrepo` was based on my understanding of [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure). However, after looking on some subversion how-to's, it seems that many people use `/home/` to store their svn repository.

### Questions:

1. What path are you using and why?
2. Is there anything wrong with using `/srv/`? Does your understanding of [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure) differe from mine?

Comment: I'm partial to /var/ - seems like a reasonable place for 'variable' data that may be edited/accessed by multiple users. (A similar example might be /var/www - I don't see this as being much different).

Comment: I've always tried to keep `/var/` for things that are transient like logs or PID locks. Always found `/var/www` completely contrary to FHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where `/srv` or `/home` is mounted. If `/srv` is mounted on a smaller `/` volume, for example, it might not be wise to put it there. Just make sure you put it on a volume with proper diskspace, performance and redundancy for your SVN servers needs.

I don't really follow FHS that much. On most of my systems I have OS/system drive on `/` on mirrored disks where all the `/usr, /var, /home, /etc` etc. is located and then I usually have one or more RAIDs mounted under`/data1, /data2` etc.

So when I put SVN repositories on these systems I usually create it under `/data1/svn`.

And as always, make sure the volumes are included in any backup solution you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put repos in /var/code or /var/svn. I figure it qualifies as "variable" data. /var is sometimes on a separate partition for files that change often, and it's backed up automatically on my machines.